# No longer possible to determine Chats of Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Until now to get Microsoft Teams messages I check the `subject` field to see if it contains "IM" as [described in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#get-messages-returns-chats-in-microsoft-teams):

> **GET messages returns chats in Microsoft Teams**
>
> In both the v1 and beta endpoints, the response of `GET /users/id/messages` includes the user's Microsoft Teams chats that occurred outside the scope of a team or channel. These chat messages have "IM" as their subject.

For the past few days, that "IM" is no longer showing up in the `subject` of the message, so now we have no information to determine if it's a Teams chat.

Answer (score 2):

The "known issue" was that `/messages` was returning these messages. It sounds like they rolled out a fix for this issue. Since this was considered a bug, the current state is how it was designed to work - `/messages` was intended to only return email messages.

This is why it's not a good idea to pull a dependency on a known issue; when they fix the issue, it breaks your code. At the moment there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to retrieve these messages but, based on this [PR in the documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/4235), it looks like it will be coming soon.

Comment: If it was a bug for them then why they did not remove the whole message but only IM from the filed subject? it does not make sense if the /messages request still return Teams chats.

Comment: That "PR in the documentation" link above no longer works. Any idea what used to be in there? Did you ever figure out this issue @Jeremy?